# Pandas: Select rows from DataFrame based on condition on columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project and I have to extract from a crosswords dataset *(id, clue, answer, answer_len, data, source, answer_occurrencies. **E.g.**:
**1222528, Brick floors of fireplaces, HEARTHS, 7.0, 2015-01-01,    pk, 1**)* the lines which have an answer that occurs more than 5 times but with different clues (*answer_occurrencies* is in fact the times an answer occurs with the same clue) but I'm not sure how to do it.
I used `value_counts()` to have a list containing the times answers occur, then I remove the answers which occur less than 5 times:

```
dropped_labels = []
for key, val in train_data["answer"].value_counts().items():
    if val < 5:
        dropped_labels.append(key)
        
fives = train_data["answer"].value_counts().drop(labels=dropped_labels)
>>>fives
ONE      77
ART      72
ERA      71
ARIA     67
TEE      60
         ..
DIOR      5
BIRTH     5
SIEVE     5
IONE      5
BESO      5
```

Now I should to select the rows from the `train_data` that have the *answer* field with the same elements of `fives` but I got stuck, since everything I used failed miserably. Are there any built-in functions I could use?
I'm new to Python, please be kind. :)

Comment: what would really help us, is if you could add a sample of your dataset, and your expected output :)

Comment: A sample of the dataset is the one I wrote in the question: 
_E.g.: 1222528, Brick floors of fireplaces, HEARTHS, 7.0, 2015-01-01, pk, 1_
What I expect is a dataset with all the answers from _fives_ like:
xxxx, First number, ONE, xx, xxxx, x, x
yyyy, Before two, ONE, yy, yyyy, y, y
zzzz, After zero, ONE, zz, zzzz, z, z
and so on. This is to be done for every other word in _fives_
(sorry for the formatting)

Comment: try running ```train_data.to_dict()``` and paste a sample output in your question please.

Comment: The dataset is very large, and a small sample would not be of any help, since a sample of 20 elements produces an empty `fives`

Answer (score 0):

you could convert both columns to equaly sized lists, ans an clu for answer and clues

```
function(ans,clu)
    ignorelist = []
    result = []
    for answer in ans: #main loop, ans by answer
        counter = 0
        index_lists = []
        ignorelist = []
        for index in range(len(ans)):
            if ans[index] = answer and clu[index] not in ignorelist
                ignorelist.append(clu[index])
                counter = counter + 1
                index_lists.append(index)
        if counter >=5
            result.append(index_lists)
    return list(dict.fromkeys(result))
```

this is untested and i havent seen ur data but hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
to_hold = train_data['answer'].value_counts() >= 5
to_hold = [key for key, value in to_hold.items() if value == True]
df = train_data[train_data['answer'].isin(to_hold)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not take into account a requirement in the question: "the lines which have an answer that occurs more than 5 times **but with different clues**". Good try, though...you are close - see if you can get all the way.

Comment: Are you sure?  Because  I read that: "The value_counts() method returns a Series containing the counts of unique values. This means, for any column in a dataframe, this method returns the count of unique entries in that column" (source: towardsdatascience.com).

Comment: Yes. The diagnostic I'm using is that solution does not refer to any column other than `answer`. It should either refer to `clue` or `answer_occurrencies`. You are correct in that `train_data['answer'].value_counts()` will count the number of occurrences of each unique `answer`. However, it is still possible that some of those answers would have a repeated clue. This isn't acceptable according the the requirements in the question.

Comment: I think you could just change your condition to: `to_hold = (train_data['answer'].value_counts() - train_data['answer_occurrencies']) >= 5` and it would probably do the job.

Comment: I'm sorry but, after some researches and tests that I've done following your advices (that I have much appreciated, thank you), I find my solution pretty consistent with the target of my task. I'm not native english speaker, so I may have explained myself wrongly.